# On Stack Overflow, aren't we supposed to downvote an incorrect answer?

Tags: discussion

When I used Stack Overflow this morning, I found an answer that was not marked as the correct answer with the green check mark. But when trying the answer out, it worked. So, I downvoted the answer that was check-marked green. Then, Stack Overflow let me do that, but suggested I add a comment explaining my downvote.

What is the correct (1) etiquette, and (2) expected behavior to use Stack Overflow's downvote functionality?

([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources/23658552#23658552) to the place I downvoted. I tried upvoting it to correct my mistake, but that didn't behave as I expected. I thought it would upvote by one, but instead it upvoted by two.)

Comment: upvote = answer useful ... downvote = answer not useful

Comment: I am sorry! I was not being specific enough. I meant, I don't know what "meta" means.

Comment: If an answer has been marked as "accepted" then it must clearly have worked for the OP. And even if it doesn't work out of the box for you doesn't mean it's incorrect and should be downvoted. And notice that there's over a year between the accepted answer and the next post, the OP might not have gone back to the question to reevaluate it after new answers were posted?

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. I will go look for 'meta' and what that's all about.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion, Hans. I was comparing the answer to my own code which was failing for a different reason.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: if you aren't *able* to provide a reason, then you shouldn't downvote. If you *can* provide a reason, you are under no *obligation* to comment, but you may do so to provide clarity to future readers. [Even more so if the answer is accepted and gets bumped to the top as a consequence.]

Comment: I see one of my errors here, also, jpp. I had an expectation about how Stack Overflow itself *should* work (in my mind, I mean). So, I tried to correct an error and made another error as a result. I wonder if Stack Overflow will attempt to monitor and change the subtle behavior of the web application by noting people's software behavior expectations and making the web application more intuitive? (Over time, I mean... ) But that's a side question, anyways.

Comment: I added a comment to that post to warn everybody about the very nasty bug it contains.  You need to read it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "If an answer has been marked as "accepted" then it *must clearly have worked for the OP*" [citation needed]

Comment: Note that the check mark does not mean that the answer is correct. It means that the asker found it the most useful. Unfortunately, it is often misinterpreted due to the excessive emphasis it imposes on the answer it is placed on.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly, that you've attempted to downvote an accepted answer that you've deemed to work, and your question here is asking why the system seems to allow you to do that when downvotes are for incorrect/non-working answers? This is not a rhetorical question, I'm just trying to make sure I'm reading your question correctly - the "So, I down-voted" is a little confusing since the "So" implies that you consider downvoting to be a logical action to take on an accepted answer, which doesn't seem to match the premise of your question.

Comment: *I thought it would up-vote by one, but instead it up-voted by two.* You can only have one vote on a post so it removed your earlier down vote, which would make the score go up by one, and then added your up vote, which would make the score go up by one again. If you only want to remove a vote without voting in the other direction you can click the arrow again to remove it (within the time limit).

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not sure how you've reached that interpretation; the OP states that the answer she found to be correct was *"not marked as the correct answer with the green check mark"*. My best parsing of the first paragraph is that she found a *non*-accepted answer that worked, and therefore downvoted the accepted answer. Which, uh, also doesn't really make much sense as a reason on its own, but isn't the same as your interpretation.

Comment: @Mark Amery: This question is *so* hard to read...

Comment: So, Su, the reason I (and, I think, BoltClock) are confused is that your first paragraph seems to suggest that you downvoted answer A simply because answer B was correct. But answer B being correct doesn't imply that answer A is incorrect. It's possible for two answers to be different but equally correct.

Comment: Ummm ... is the dup link for this Question correct?

Comment: @StephenC The target is about downvoting questions, this one is about downvoting answers. I'm not sure, but -- close. The answers are both "whether it's useful".

Comment: @SuLlewellyn I don't understand the question, the second answer is correct doesn't imply that all others are incorrect. I don't see why you should downvote the first answer.

Comment: Okay, Guys, I get it already. I don't understand why I get a -10 for being a newbie and asking a question I COULD NOT FIND THE ANSWER TO! Don't blame the asker if Stack Overflow's find functionality is poorly designed for the user.

Comment: @SuLlewellyn How is it's the fault of SO search that people can't understand what your question is asking?

Comment: @Servery Don't worry I will never ask a question on SO ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how stack overflow specifies when you should downvote

> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an
> egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is
> clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

They also specify

> Voting down, also known as "casting downvotes",
> is how the community indicates which questions and answers are least
> useful.

And talk about alternatives to downvoting

> The upvote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus
> on: pushing great content to the top. Downvoting should be reserved
> for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication
> and editing.
>
> Instead of voting down:
>
> - If the post is spammy or offensive, flag it.
> - If the question is duplicate or off-topic, flag it for moderator attention.
> - If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 4):

If you find an answer to be incorrect, you should probably downvote it, so that other users know that it either didn't work or perhaps has some terrible side effect like a security vulnerability, or running out of memory.

The gray line of when to and when not to downvote answers is a very long discussion, so I am not really going to get into the nuance of it, please look around here and on Meta Stack Exchange for that history; bring a good drink.

However, one thing is very straightforward: the platform (Stack Overflow) will not determine what should and should not be downvoted for you. This means, as you found out, that it is possible to downvote an accepted answer; it also means it is possible to upvote a highly downvoted answer. As far as accepted answers go, in general that just means that answer is the one which the question asker felt solved the problem best *for them*; different answers may work better than that for your situation (or theirs), and while rare there are inaccurate or just plain dangerous accepted answers on Stack Overflow.

As for your *exact* situation, let's just assume the post was at +10 / -0, a net of +10. When you downvoted it, it became +10 / -1, a net of +9. When you upvoted it *after* downvoting, it removed your downvote, and gave an upvote, creating +11 / -0. This may seem to have changed the post with two upvotes from 9 to 11, but in reality, it was just the effect of removing your downvote and adding an upvote. Keep in mind, there is a 5 minute window for changing votes after casting them (unless the post is subsequently edited in which case you may then change it at any time following the edit).