# Caucus badge notification being triggered multiple times

Tags: bug, badges

Caucus badge notifications are causing a raucous in my achievements feed.

I opened the [2019 Moderator Elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) and eventually received 3 notifications about the Caucus badge being earned. After navigating to the [2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380885/2019-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1) I received another notification for the Caucus badge.

Now, I get a notification after opening the Mod Q&A questionnaire every once and a while. May not occur every time, but if I open the Questionnaire and then go back to SO main page eventually I get a notification for the badge. The badge counter is not increasing, so looks to be just the notification being triggered.

Using: Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763

[image]

Comment: Not frist! Missed it by 5 minutes!

Comment: That'll teach me to take 5 minutes drawing freehand circles